# VS Code debugger not using virtual environment in WSL?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-venv

I'm currently learning how to make Django projects but the material uses the Linux command shell and the instructors use Macs. I run a Windows machine, so I have to use WSL and Bash.

I'm trying to use the VS Code debugger with a Python virtual environment created in a Bash terminal with WSL. I create my virtual environments by opening up a terminal in VS Code, entering the Bash terminal, then typing `python -m venv venvname`.

On the bottom right of VS Code there's something like this where I can click on the Python version number to change the interpreter.[image]
If I then click "Enter interpreter path" then "Find" it brings up a Windows Explorer menu where I can direct it to a python executable, but it seems that virtual environments for Linux (created through a Bash terminal) don't have a python.exe. I have a python file with seemingly no extension that I am also unable to open.

I've tried using a venv created with Windows powershell in VSC just for testing purposes. After creating the venv, VSC gives me a notification ask if I want to use the newly created venv (I get no such prompt when creating venvs with bash) and confirming makes the Python version number also indicate that it's using a venv. The files also has an actual python.exe file but it comes with other problems. I can't run the Activate.ps1 script to enter the venv in VSC. I *can* activate the venv by running command prompt/powershell outside of VSC as administrator, but it seems to have issues installing older versions of packages when I try to install from file with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.